# Creating UI for dynamically loaded content in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to build an autocomplete on a big dataset and have already implemented the search algorithm for it. Now for the UI part I want to create a dropdown exactly like the dropdown of a select item. What is the best way to create it so that it works on all browsers.

**HTML**:

```
<input class="autocomplete">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.autocomplete').keyup(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url://URL
        success:funtion(){
            // Convert the input to an input with dropdown
        }
    })
})
```

Please Note : I don't want something like twitter typeahead or jQuery UI's autocomplete to do the searching for me. I just want something whom I give my data and it makes something like select dropdown box out of it

Comment: see this:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/facebook-and-linkedin-like-searching.html it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option for you to use jQuery UI try the [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote):

```
$( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: //URL,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

    }
});
```

Comment: HI , I dont want anyone doing search on my data. But justwhatever i give it , it makes a clean dropdown out of it

Comment: Did I understand right: You want to search once with the data entered in the input field and after that the input field should become a dropdown with the search results? So there is no possibility to search again?

Comment: It is possibility to search again.UI is very similar to the google's search dropdown. But I dont want any external agent to interfere in my searched result

Comment: What du you mean with "external agent"? JQuery UI is not an agent. It's a script library running in the user's browser and nowhere else...

Answer (score 0):

It is not too straightforward to come up with a decent implementation for custom combo boxes. If you want a (searchable) combo box, you can use something like jquery chosen

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

If you want something that manages the autocomplete part of the logic for you, then something like Twtitter's typeahead could be of great help.

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

It will be hard to build something by hand that can match the kind of user experience you can get if you use some of the other open source options.

Comment: I have already looked at these options but didn't seem to workout for me. My data set is too large to feed them and also I dont want to make my complete search data set as public